# When do we use " public class Something { " vs " class Something { "

Tags: java

for example,

1.

```
public class Something {
     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Hello World");

     }
}
```

2.

```
class Something {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.print("Hello World");

      }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are different access modifiers: 1 is public and the lack if modifier in 2 indicates default access. For more information check:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

This changes the access for this class. If you're using only one package, then it doesn't matter, but `public` allows this class to be visible outside the package, while no identifier does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

`public`, `protected` and `private` are access modifiers. Public means that the class may be accessed by any other class, `protected` means it can be accessed by any *subclass*, `private` by the class itself, no modifier (just `class`) means "package private", so the method may be accessed by classes from the same package.